# QuickBlox: How to get all members of room?

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, chat, quickblox

How can we get all member of room in QuickBlox iOS SDK. In web SDk of QuickBlox we can find by bellow link. but I am not able to find same for iOS SDK

http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Managing_members

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For retrieving the all members of the group first fetch the particular dialogue for which you want to get the member and it gives you this kind of response.

```
Dialogs: (
ID:554864c6535c12ac9a0f63dc                      
Room JID:17320_554864c6535c12ac9a0f63dc@muc.chat.quickblox.com                      
name:3                      
photo:(null)                      
type:2                      
lastMessage:(null)                      
lastMessageDate:(null)                      
occupantIDs:(\n    2067069,\n    2107873,\n    2976970\n)                      
userID:2976970                      
unreadMessagesCount:0                      
lastMessageUserID:0"
)
```

here you can see you have the occupants id of the all users in the group now you have to find the all users with this occupants ids.

```
    NSArray *occupantsUsersIDs = [dialogname valueForKey:@"occupantIDs"];
    //
    [QBRequest usersWithIDs:occupantsUsersIDs page:pagedRequest successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *page, NSArray *users) {

     NSLog(@"Users %@",users);
        //
    } errorBlock:nil];
```

Comment: here we are not adding user into occupantIDS.

Comment: when you creating the group you have to specify the occupantsIDs right?

Comment: Yes but I am only giving my occupantID not the whole members ID

Comment: Okay then the group dialogue have the occupants id you can use that for getting members. That i have mention in the answer.

Comment: bapu sends regards to you